# Macro to remove all non-numeric characters from its argument

Tags: strings, format

In a custom class I defined a custom command to typeset a telephone number,

```
\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\def\@phone{#1}}
```

I use this `\@phone` macro inside my class when I want to replace with the value from the "variable". But there are some cases that I need to use a cleaned up version of the phone string. Normally `\phone` contains something like `(623) 21-23-12-31`; however, I want to create a `\phoneclean` which outputs just the numbers as `62321231231`. How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can loop through dropping droppable characters (spaces are lost automatically here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo#1{%
\ifx\relax#1\else
\ifx(#1\else\ifx)#1\else\ifx-#1\else#1\fi\fi\fi
\expandafter\foo
\fi}

\begin{document}

\foo(623) 21-23-12-31\relax

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Lin `\ifx(#1\else`  reads "if the next character is `(` do nothing else ....

Comment: Yes. I noticed later, hence why I have removed the question. But I think is good to keep your answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Could `\foo` be made fully exandable?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have used the macro defined by you and created a new one with the following code `\newcommand{\phoneclean}{\foo\@phone\relax}` inside my custom class. When I call (inside the custom class) the `\phoneclean` macro. It still shows the phone with the dashes, parenthesis and spaces .

Comment: @Lin `\expandafter\foo\@phone\relax`

Comment: @Mico `\foo` is expandable, but you just need to expand its argument first see the comment above

Comment: Thanks, David, for this follow-up.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which makes use of Lua's powerful `string.gsub` function to purge all non-numeric characters from the macro's argument.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro
\newcommand\phoneclean[1]{\luaexec{% "%D" matches "any non-numeric character"
   tex.sprint (( string.gsub ( "#1" , "\%D" , "" ) )) }}

\begin{document}
\phoneclean{(623) 21-23-12-31}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Because `\luaexec` is fully expandable, so is `\phoneclean`. Hence, instead of executing `\phoneclean{(623) 21-23-12-31}` directly, one could also first define `\zzz` via `\newcommand{\zzz}{(623) 21-23-12-31}` and then execute `\phoneclean{\zzz}`.

Comment: Another power tool in the lualatex arsenal.

Comment: Remark: To handle a use case such as `\def\zzz{\small\{623\} 21-23-12-31} \phoneclean{\zzz}`, just change `"#1"` to `\luastringO{#1}` inside the `\phoneclean` macro. (`\luastringO` is a command provided by the [luacode](https://ctan.org/pkg/luacode) package; it expands its argument *once*.)

Answer (score 4):

You can map the input and keep the digits.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getphonenumber}{m}
 {
  \lin_getphoneno:e { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \lin_getphoneno:n
 {
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__lin_getphoneno_check:n
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \lin_getphoneno:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__lin_getphoneno_check:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {0}{0} {1}{1} {2}{2} {3}{3} {4}{4} {5}{5} {6}{6} {7}{7} {8}{8} {9}{9}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getphonenumber{(623) 21-23-12-31}

\edef\test{\getphonenumber{(623) 21-23-12-31}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\def\phoneno{(623) 21-23-12-31}

\getphonenumber{\phoneno}

\edef\test{\getphonenumber{\phoneno}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

You see that `\getphonenumber` also works when the number is stored in a macro.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With this token cycle, alphabetical characters, TeX grouping, symbols, macros, and spaces are all screened out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\phoneclean[1]{%
  \tokencycle
  {\ifnum`##1>`\/ \ifnum`##1<`\:##1\fi\fi}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {}
  {}%
  #1\endtokencycle
}
\begin{document}
\phoneclean{(623) 21-23-12-31}

\phoneclean{(623) 21-23-12-31(c)}

\phoneclean{{623} 21-23-12-31}

\phoneclean{\small\{623\} 21-23-12-31}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for coming up with `\small\{623\} 21-23-12-31` as a use case. This use case prompted me to post a follow-up comment below my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following uses a low level token-loop and check for a digit (only category 12 digits should pass this filter and remain in the output, in particular macros that expand to a valid number are filtered as well). It is fully expandable, expands exactly in two steps and the result doesn't expand any further inside of an `\edef`. It assumes that `\stop` is never part of the argument, and that the argument doesn't contain braced groups.

If you give an optional `*` after `\sanitisephone` the first token in the input is expanded once (allowing a single macro as input).

There is a bit of trickery involved to get the `*`-variant using `\NewExpandableDocument` and still being expandable in exactly two steps (note that this trickery can be considered breaking coding styleguides of the kernel team).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\providecommand\@gobblefour[4]{}

\newcommand\phonenumber{}
\newcommand\phone[1]{\edef\phonenumber{\unexpanded{#1}}}

\newcommand\filternondigit[1]
  {%
    \ifnum\@ne<1\noexpand#1
      \@firstoftwo
    \fi
    \@gobbletwo\unexpanded{#1}%
  }

\newcommand\sanitisephone
  {\unexpanded\expanded\sanitisephone@args}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\sanitisephone@args{s +m}
  {{{\IfBooleanT{#1}\expandafter\sanitisephone@#2\stop}}}
\newcommand\sanitisephone@[1]
  {\sanitisephone@ifstop#1\@gobblefour\stop\filternondigit{#1}\sanitisephone@}
\long\def\sanitisephone@ifstop#1\stop{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\phone{(623) 21-23-12-31}
\edef\mytmp{\sanitisephone*\phonenumber}\texttt{\meaning\mytmp}

\edef\mytmp{\sanitisephone{(623) 21-23-12-31}}\texttt{\meaning\mytmp}
\end{document}
```